# Для чего нужны новые html5 теги?

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Я активно использую HTML5, такие теги как article, header, footer... и т.д. Но что они дают на данный момент кроме логичности кода? Ведь это все те же div-ы

Одно из моих предположений - это поисковая оптимизация. Что еще?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Семантика и оптимизация для поисковых систем, логичность кода, как вы и сказали :-)